# adjust webpage to facebook tab with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, facebook

I am trying to adjust webpage to facebook tab, I created new page for the tab and load the content from the targeted webpage, all go well the issue is that I can't re-size this content to fit 810px.

**HTML:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/facebook-tab.js"></script>  
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="facebook-contant"> 
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $( "#facebook-contant" ).load('recommendations.html #rec-board-holder');
});
```

any advice how to change the load content size?

Comment: Depends on the html in recommencations.html. Can you show us?

Comment: How do I effect the recommencations.html css?

Comment: It still depends... what is inside recommandations.html? You can style it from you first html file because it gets inserted in the same dom. Is this facebook app online an accessible anywhere?

Comment: By default, a <div> occupies 100% of the container's width. Which would be Facebook's tab container, whose width is already specified by you on the App Dashboard (or so I've read on Facebook's Page Tab Tutorial). Of course when testing outside Facebook, this container is missing, but you might mimic the effect by resizing your web browser window. My question to you would be: what more is there you want to achieve in terms of styling?

Answer (score 5):

You can try canvas setSize method to adjust tab page height and width, reference:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

Method called

```
FB.Canvas.setSize
```

It takes arguments in json object like

```
FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 640, height: 480 });
```

You can specify width and height here. You need to call javascript sdk of facebook to call this method.

Answer (score 1):

You should use heigh / width in percentage(%) rather px / em. change the css file.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but here's my thoughts anyway. If you're trying to change elements in the loaded content, you could just add a function that fires after the content is loaded and make the adjustments.

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $( "#facebook-contant" ).load('recommendations.html #rec-board-holder',function(){
        //access and make adjustments here
    });
});
```